# What does the phrase 'I feel like a pig in a wig' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I heard this phrase in an [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V43L7Y9pkA):

> I feel like a pig in a wig.

I understand from the context that it is like nothing, ugly or something similar.
I have read that they use words that sound good together to express a feeling or so.

Could you help me understand this better?

Comment: There is insufficient context in the question. Can you add more of the transcript leading up to it?

Comment: Note Jennifer Aniston didn't understand it either. It's not a set phrase. It probably was used first by the poet Thomas Hood in his children's poem *The headlong career and woful ending of precocious piggy*. Read the [poem](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=2SctAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22where%20are%20you%20going%20to%2C%20you%20little%20pig%22&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q=%22where%20are%20you%20going%20to,%20you%20little%20pig%22&f=false).

Comment: I thought it meant to feel oddly.

Comment: Ugly and conspicuous, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that something or someone who is usually considered to be unattractive is attempting to look more attractive through the addition of some superficial ornament (clothes, make-up or, indeed, a wig) that, however, fools nobody.

A similar phrase is "mutton dressed as lamb".

Answer (score 0):

It means obvious, conspicuous, sticking out like a sore thumb or you feel like you're not fooling anybody- depending on the context.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this (e.g., a reference)?